# Fail to read localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, session-storage

I have a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/UOrq5vb32ajhu4F7OfPM?p=preview) to set a value in localStorage:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <script>
    localStorage.setItem('test', "hadddddha");
  </script>
</html>
```

And I have a code http://www.addbba.com/testLocalStorage.html to get it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <script>
    var test = localStorage.getItem('test');
    console.log(test)
  </script>
</html>
```

Oddly, the console shows the value is `null`. Does anyone know what happened?

Comment: are both your files are the same domain? if not, you may be having a cross-origin issue.

Comment: No, they are not... do you know how to share value cross-origin?

Comment: I do not believe, you can use localstorage or sessionstorage if your not in the same domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage localStorage is specific to a document's origin. Can you confirm that you are reading a value from localStorage using the same origin as where you wrote the value?

Comment: OK, `plunker` and `addbba` does not have same origin. Do you know how to share values cross-origin?

Comment: You can try sending a cross origin XMLHttpRequest