# How does localStorage work on Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, local-storage

**Edit.** I am confused by how localStorage is sandboxed. I create a folder and a simple webpage on MacBook Air without bundling any other files. The webpage has only a button and a link to the same page. On button click, the button count is read from local storage, increased by one, and the incremented value is written to local storage using the same key:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <script>
    function getCount() {return parseInt(localStorage.getItem("count") || 0)}
    function incCount() {localStorage.setItem("count", getCount()+1)}
    function setText() {document.getElementById("btn").innerHTML = getCount() + " clicks"}
  </script>
</head>
<body onpageshow ="setText()">
  <button id="btn" onclick="incCount(); setText()">clicks</button>
  <a href="/">open the same page</a>
</body>
```

Now I `npm install -g http-server`, run `http-server` from within the folder, and do the following test on Firefox. Following the advices in the comments, I've created a new profile on Firefox 57.0.1 to do the following tests. I've also run the tests on Firefox Nightly and the results are the same.

**Test 1**

1. Go to `http://localhost:8080` on **"tab 1"** in non-private browsing mode. Delete all local storage if any.
2. Click the button ten times to increase the button count to 10.
3. Command-click the link on the webpage to open the same page on a new tab (**"tab 2"**).
4. Close tab 1.
5. Refresh tab 2. Denote the button count at this point **X**.

**Test 2**

1. Go to `http://localhost:8080` on **"tab 1"** in non-private browsing mode. Delete all local storage if any.
2. Click the button once.
3. Cmd-click to open the same page on a new tab (**"tab 2"**).
4. Go to google on tab 1.
5. Click the button once on tab 2.
6. Press back button on tab 1 and refresh tab 1. Denote the button counts on tab 1 and tab 2 respectively by **A** and **B**.
7. Click the button once on tab 2. Then refresh tab 1. Denote the button counts on tab 1 and tab 2 respectively by **C** and **D**.

Here are the results:

- Firefox in normal mode: (X,A,B,C,D)=(10,1,2,3,3).
- Firefox in private browsing mode: (X,A,B,C,D)=(0,1,1,2,2).
- Chrome (normal or private mode) or Safari (normal mode only; I can't put anything into local storage in private mode): (X,A,B,C,D)=(10,2,2,3,3).

The results generated from Firefox's feel very chaotic. Why is A=1 in normal mode and why is C=2 in private mode? If different tabs share the same storage area in normal mode but different storage areas in private mode, we should instead have A=2 in normal mode and C=1 in private mode.

So, my question is, is this a bug in Firefox. If this is legitimate, how exactly does local storage work on Firefox? There is a similar question ("[Fail to read localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46249215/fail-to-read-localstorage)") on this site, but in that question, the documents involved came from different origins.

Comment: What version of Firefox are you using? on 57.0 64-bit Windows, The behavior is exactly as you've described it. 

If you are using private browsing, I believe that Firefox will use scope the storage for each tab.

Comment: can you check if event works? `window.addEventListener('storage', function (event) {
  if (event.key == 'count') document.getElementById("btn").innerHTML = event.newValue + " clicks"
});`

Comment: Note that different ports are considered different origins. Bit confusing following your steps

Comment: @nipuna777 It's 57.0.1 on 64-bit Mac OS X. The results are identical with both non-private and private windows.

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks. I used the same port on both tabs throughout the test. It's just port 8080 was used (on both tabs) in the first test and the test was done again on port 3333 (on both tabs) in the second test.

Comment: @bigless Event works. I've used storage events to propagate data across tabs before without problems. But my concern here is the initial value of `localStorage.getItem()` on first load, because we cannot use storage events to synchronise data in some circumstances. E.g. open tab 1, click the button a few times, open tab 2, go to google on tab 1, click the button once on tab 2. Although tab 1 isn't closed, it's on google's front page now and cannot respond to the storage event.

Comment: @bigless And most importantly, what I want to know is how local storage persists. (Across tabs or not? Throughout history or not? What about private browsing or non-private browsing? Etc..) I've tried to read the spec, but to my understanding, local storage should behave like it does in Chrome or Safari. I'm a complete newbie in web development and the spec is a bit abstract :-P, so I'm not sure if Firefox's behaviour is a bug or not.

Comment: @user740006 What you are describing could be a bug. Could you try installing an earlier version(or the nightly) and see if the problem persists? 

Also, for private browsing and local storage refer to this: https://gist.github.com/JohnAllsopp/1470989

In FF it's treated as sessionStorage(per tab)

Comment: @nipuna777 Thanks. I'll try it later (am on some slow public wifi now) to see what happens.

Comment: Try making a new Firefox profile (run `firefox -P` to open the profile switcher) and seeing if the problem still occurs on the new profile. This will eliminate privacy settings and extensions as possible causes.